# What's wrong with my group_concat SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `b10g_entries` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `permalink` text NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `fullcontent` text NOT NULL,
  `introcontent` text NOT NULL,
  `dateadded` datetime NOT NULL,
  `lastedited` datetime NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `comments` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `published` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=299 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `b10g_tag_map` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `b10g_tags` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And i'm trying to get first 25 blog entries with their tags (that's why I use many-to-many relationship) using this query:

```
SELECT b10g_entries.*, GROUP_CONCAT( b10g_tags.name SEPARATOR ', ') 
AS tags FROM b10g_entries 
LEFT JOIN b10g_tag_map ON b10g_entries.id = b10g_tag_map.entry_id 
LEFT JOIN b10g_tags ON b10g_tag_map.tag_id = b10g_tags.id LIMIT 0, 25;
```

But I only get one record back. What's wrong with this query?

Comment: hmm. interesting - so TEXT fields really should be in different table as content can get quite big comparably to the rest of the columns - good point, I haven't thought of that. I was definitely going to add indexes to BIGINT's in reference table, but thanks for pointing that one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a **GROUP BY** clause.

Now, you're getting a list of ALL tags found anywhere in the set. Instead, you only want the ones within the group (by entry).

```
SELECT b10g_entries.*, GROUP_CONCAT( b10g_tags.name SEPARATOR ', ') 
AS tags FROM b10g_entries 
LEFT JOIN b10g_tag_map ON b10g_entries.id = b10g_tag_map.entry_id 
LEFT JOIN b10g_tags ON b10g_tag_map.tag_id = b10g_tags.id 
GROUP BY b10g_entries.id
```

Comment: I would like to note that this approach may not be very performant. Test in your environment against something more like a secondary query to get the tags.

Comment: awesome. awesome to the max. thanks zanlok. I actually had GROUP BY b10g_entries.id in my code but mistakenly placed it after LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate function, but have not used a `GROUP BY` clause, so your result will be one row.

Note that in MySQL it is permissible to use a `GROUP BY` with only one column specified while many more appear in the `SELECT` list, but that is not portable to other RDBMS.  So instead, I have joined `b10g_entries` in a second time to connect all the other columns from that table, while only using the `id` in the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT
  b10g_entries_all.*, 
  GROUP_CONCAT( b10g_tags.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS tags
FROM
  /* Main table, used gor GROUP BY aggregate */
  b10g_entries
  /* self join to pull in other columns without needing to put them in GROUP BY */
  JOIN b10g_entries b10g_entries_all ON b10g_entries.id = b10g_entries_all.id 
  LEFT JOIN b10g_tag_map ON b10g_entries.id = b10g_tag_map.entry_id 
  LEFT JOIN b10g_tags ON b10g_tag_map.tag_id = b10g_tags.id 
/* group on the entry id */
GROUP BY b10g_entries.id
LIMIT 0, 25;
```